# Where can I find the European equivalent ETFs from a USD superdiversified 10 ETFs portfolio

Tags: etf, currency, portfolio, bond-etf, passive-income

I have been using this superdiversified 10 ETFs portfolio.
To lower the risk it's composed from stocks and bonds across the globe and includes some commodities.
Being in USD currency and the Euro being on the rise I wanted to find equivalents ETFs (tracking the same indexes) in Euros.
Where could I find the equivalents ETFs I could buy in Europe (ideally from France) ?

```
+--------+--------------------------------------------------+-------------+
| ticker | Exchange-traded Fund                             | Percent (%) |
+--------+--------------------------------------------------+-------------+
| BWX    | SPDR Bloomberg Barclays Intl Treasury Bond       |  13         |
| EMLC   | VanEck Vectors JP Morgan Emer Mkts Loc Curr Bond |  10         |
| BND    | Vanguard Total Bond Market                       |   9         |
+--------+--------------------------------------------------+-------------+
| IAU    | iShares Gold Trust                               |  11         |
| DBC    | PowerShares DB Commodity Tracking                |   5         |
+--------+--------------------------------------------------+-------------+
| VEU    | Vanguard FTSE All-World ex-U.S.                  |  17         |
| VWO    | Vanguard FTSE Emerging Markets Index             |  14         |
| VNQI   | Vanguard Global ex-U.S. Real Estate              |   4         |
| VNQ    | Vanguard REIT                                    |   6         |
| VTI    | Vanguard Total Stock Market                      |  11         |
+--------+--------------------------------------------------+-------------+
| Composite Portfolio                                       | 100         |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+-------------+
```

Comment: If they track they same indexes, the value would be always the USD value multiplied by the currency conversion. There is no difference which ones you buy (which is probably the reason they won't exist)